# Java and Android Studio listener syntax

Tags: java, methods, anonymous-class

I am learning Java while at the same time comparing its structure to Android Studio Java code in order to be more familiar. In the code below,
can you please explain the syntax of `new View.OnclickListener(){...}`?

```
button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        clickBack();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Without Anonymous classes, the implementation of same code looks like below

```
class ClickListener extends View.OnClickListener{
   @Override
   public void onClick(View view){
       clickBack();
   }
}
button2.setOnClickListener(ClickListener());
```

In java, you can directly create instance of an `Interface`, know as anonymous inner class, it will be created for you by compiler. so implementation becomes

```
button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
          clickBack();
       }
});
```

if using `Java8`, here is more concise way using lambdas

```
button2.setOnClickListener(view -> clickBack());
```

Answer (score -1):

If simply explain what it is
we will writing method in for what will happens when we will click the button.
for that first we need to identify our xml button id in java class and need to be find with method.
Then after we can call Button Seton click listener.